# Looking for a generic wallet solution with focus on security

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, bitcoin-cash, ethereum, bitcoin-gold

As above, I am looking for a coin agnostic wallet solution with all basic functionalities of a wallet, particularly multi-sig. Primary coin focus is on bitcoin, bitcoin cash, bitcoin gold, ethereum, litecoin and ripple. ICO is not part of consideration and language is not important.

Anyone has done a comparison to share please.

Thank you.

Comment: There are hundreds of different types of cryptocurrency, so I'm voting to close this as too broad.

Comment: Thank you for comment. I have edited to make it more specific as suggested

Comment: Good edit; I've nominated the question to be re-opened. I'm not sure if such a wallet exists (except maybe as an e-wallet in an exchange), so I'll be interested to see the answer :-)